# .NET MAUI Binding Path and Source in the MVVM Pattern

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, maui

I have a `List<Foo> FooList` that resides in my ViewModel & I have a `Models` folder detailing the `Foo` object with its properties (`FooName`, `FooTime`, etc). I need my Picker's `ItemSource` to be bound to `FooList` but I need `ItemDisplayBinding` to be bound to `Foo.FooName`. Despite reading all the binding documentation and trying many combinations I can't get it to work.

For example, I've tried to avail:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding FooList}"
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Source={models:Foo}, Path=FooName}"
```

In a `CollectionView`, it's easy enough to render elements with `Foo.FooName` via the `DataTemplate`, but a `Picker` doesn't have that property. I'd really appreciate some guidance, as I've long wondered how to use the Source/Path properties for more than `x:Reference`s to XAML-defined `x:Name`s.

Comment: “{Binding FooName}”

Comment: That should not matter.  Picker knows that the ItemDisplayBinding is relative to the ItemsSource.  See the example in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding

Comment: @Anubis4574 I suggest you listen to Jason.

Comment: @Jason my apologies, I tried your suggestion and received an IntelliSense warning regarding DataContext set to the ViewModel, but I should've ran the solution to actually see that it does work - so thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason said that you can `"{Binding FooName}"` directly. And you can refer to the official doc: [Populate a Picker with data using data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker?view=net-maui-7.0#populate-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding):

> When binding to a list of objects, the Picker must be told which property to display from each object. This is achieved by setting the `ItemDisplayBinding` property to the required property from each object. In the code examples above, the Picker is set to display each `Monkey.Name` property value.

In addition, you said that it's easy for `CollectionView` to do same thing with the help of `DataTemplate`. You can see this: [Create a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-datatemplate):

> A `DataTemplate` is used to specify the appearance of data, and typically uses data binding to display data. A common usage scenario for data templates is when displaying data from a collection of objects in a control such as a CollectionView or CarouselView. For example, when a CollectionView is bound to a collection of `Person` objects, the `CollectionView.ItemTemplate` property can be set to a `DataTemplate` that defines the appearance of each `Person` object in the CollectionView. The `DataTemplate` will contain objects that bind to property values of each `Person` object.

About Source/Path of Binding, you can check the official doc: [Binding path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path?view=net-maui-7.0), it's very good and detailed.